# FTP Delete non empty directory

Tags: unix, ftp

I am connected to a Unix server and I am trying to, via FTP, delete the directory `dir` with several files in it. If I use

```
ftp> delete dir/*
```

I get

> 550 Wildcard is ambiguous.

When I use

```
ftp> prompt off
Interactive mode off.
ftp> mdelete dir/*
```

I still get

> 550 Wildcard is ambiguous.

When I try

```
ftp> glob
Globbing on.
ftp> mdelete dir
```

I'm prompted for every file.

How can I easily delete/empty-and-delete a directory without getting prompted for every file?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I got it to work in two steps, on a server with restricted access, no SFTP, only FTP through commandline.

Like this :

```
mdelete folder_name/*
rmdir folder_name
```

Comment: This only if there aren't sub-folders within `folder_name`

Comment: It seems that this does not work after 2020, as they removed the ability to remove files with wildcards.

Answer (score 20):

If you've hidden files or folders on your server (for example .folder), you have to set the lftp list-options to "-a".

So this worked for me:

```
$ lftp -u user,pass server
> set ftp:list-options -a
> cd /folder/to/be/empty/
/folder/to/be/empty/> glob -a rm -r *
```

Comment: See also [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/221436/delete-recursive-directories-with-ftp-command-on-bash) on Serverfault. And [this](http://happy-coding.com/transfer-a-file-to-a-remote-server-using-lftp/). `lftp -u login,password ftp_server_location -e "rm -r directory_to_delete; exit"`

Comment: My favorite answer, lftp is so much easier.

Comment: It's too bad `lftp` doesn't remove all the files in a folder as one request. It seems to do a round trip for every single file, so it's very slow.

Comment: @joeytwiddle That's not `lftp` fault. It is a limitation of the FTP protocol.

Answer (score 19):

Use lftp to log into your server, this supports the `rm -r` command.

```
lftp user, password server
```

then:

```
rm -r directory
```

the `-r` stands for "recursive".

info:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_%28Unix%29#Options

Comment: So this means there's no way to do it with FTP?

Answer (score 4):

$ ftp -i ...

will turn off prompting on mdel, which is what you want.  It can't be done inside ftp.

Comment: You just saved my life with that ' -i '

Answer (score -1):

rmdir directoryName

this directory must be in the current directory however.

cheatsheet: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html

Comment: ```rmdir -f <directory>``` you can use **-f** to force a delete

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Filezilla, and it deletes folders recursively. I believe the ftp does not have a command that recursively deletes folders.