# Removing non empty directory from ftp, ruby, Net::FTP

Tags: ruby, ftp

I have a project where I need to remove non empty folders from an ftp server. I have tried with `ftp.rmdir()`, but I got an error message stating

> Folder is not empty

I then tried just moving the directory with the `ftp.rename()` method, but I got the same error message there.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, FTP requires you to remove all files recursively.

Hers is a good example of how one can do:

https://github.com/dsabanin/BetterFTP

```
def rm_r(path)
 return if @deleted_paths_cache.include?(path)
 @deleted_paths_cache << path
 if directory?(path) 
  chdir path

  begin
    files = nlst
    files.each {|file| rm_r "#{path}/#{file}"}
  rescue Net::FTPTempError
    # maybe all files were deleted already
  end

  rmdir path
else
  rm(path)
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to delete all the files in that directory first using [mdelete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490662.aspx)

`mdelete folder_name/*`

then you should be able to remove the directory using [rmdir](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490678.aspx)

`rmdir folder_name`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749517/ftp-delete-non-empty-directory)