# E2E tests - removing FTP directory

Tags: ftp, command

My e2e Angular tests create ftp folder that contains subfolders with few files. Then, after test execution I would like to remove the same folder, but I'm getting error "550 Remove directory operation failed.".
All (creation, remove) is done by `ftp` console.
What I observed is that it removes folders without problem when it's empty, but when it have some subfolders or files inside, then it doesn't work.
Command I'm trying to use is:
`rm -r foldername`
in localisation where it's placed. I want remove all files and folders inside (assuming that inside structure is not known).

Comment: What *"`ftp` console"*? Windows or Linux?

Comment: Test are running on Ubuntu, but in general I'm talking about https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001246.htm

Comment: See [FTP Delete non empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10749517/850848).

Comment: Precising: tests are played automatically on Ubuntu, but it must have option to remove it also on Windows. For us best option would be to remove it without installing anything new.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, this requires installation of lftp, which I'll preferably omit (additional dependency that has to be installed on each machine running test).

Comment: What requires an installation of `lftp`? The accepted answer by @EcchiOli uses a plain `ftp`. And I'm pretty  sure that those commands work both in Windows and Linux `ftp`.

Comment: Comment to his answer - @EcchiOli solution works only for files, not for subfolders.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that you need subfolders too. Anyway, it still answers your question. **Plain `ftp` cannot remove subfolders.** You will have to use another client or script it with some more powerful language (e.g. Python).